# Using git reset --soft, Marking a commit so that you can squash *down* to it later

Tags: git, git-reset

Looking to squash commits, so that a publicly facing project doesn't have meaningless commit messages like "temp" or "temp123".

I am looking for a way to use `git reset --soft HEAD~5`, but instead of randomly picking the number 5, I want to go back through the Git logs and find all the the commits that do not match a pattern, and once I hit the pattern I stop. So let's say my `git log` commit messages look like:

```
temp123
fooGit
temp
fml
temp24
tmp69
tttoday
publish/release:xyz
```

so I would squash the top 7 most recent commits, but leave everything "below" `publish/release:xyz`.

For fairly complicated reasons, `git merge --squash` issued from the public facing branch won't work for me because I am end up deleting or renaming files quite a bit in a project on the private branch and so there are just too many merge conflicts. It seems to me, after trying it several ways, that it's best to push to the public facing branch with -f, and not worry about conflicts in that way.

I think the better approach in my case is to squash commits like so:

```
# on private "dev" branch
# make a bunch of changes, rename files, yadda yadda
git add . && git add -A && git commit -am "temp" &&
git checkout -b squash_branch  # we do squashing on this branch to be safer
git reset --soft head~15 # apparently this undoes commits for the last 15 commits
git commit -am "A serious commit message"
git push -u public master -f  # overwrite public master
```

this way, I never have to resolve conflicts between the public facing branch and the private development branch, which can be super pointless and annoying from my experience.

However, the problem I am trying to solve has to do with the number 15 above. I am simply just guessing about how many commits to "squash". I would rather know the exact number to squash.

Perhaps I can do a squash of all commits that do not have a Git commit message that fits a certain pattern? So when I run the squash, I create a commit message with a certain pattern, let's say it's "XYZ". Could I run `git reset --soft HEAD~(some git commit pattern matching to find the count)`?

Also one more question. After doing the squash (`git reset --soft`) on the `squash_branch`, should I merge that branch back into the private `dev` branch?

Comment: The dev branch does not track public/master, the dev branch tracks private/dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* find the count, but this is a little bit dangerous as it will be the *wrong number* if there are merge commits present in the chain (not illustrated here):

```
git rev-list --count HEAD^{/publish/release:xyz}..HEAD
```

The notation `rev^{/text}` means "starting from the given `rev`, search each commit message (a la `git log --grep`) for the given *text*".  So the first expression matches the commit with `publish/release:xyz` in its commit message.  The `..` syntax then uses that commit's ID to *remove* that commit and earlier commits from the set of commits selected by the name `HEAD`.  The `--count` then gives us a count of remaining commits.  Hence if your graph looks like this:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o--o   <-- HEAD
```

where `*` is the commit with the *text* in it, this discards commit `*` and the other further-left commits, leaving the four final `o` commit nodes to which `HEAD` points.  The `--count` then counts those four commits and prints `4`.

Overall, though, this is a bad strategy.  It's much better to start by marking the point with a *branch or tag name*.  A branch or tag name identifies a commit by *pointing to it*.  Instead of trying to find commit `*` by pattern, just mark it when you make it:

```
git tag xyz
```

Now you have this:

```
     tag:xyz
        |
        v
...--o--*--o--o--o   <-- HEAD -> dev
```

and `xyz..HEAD` gets you the right set of commits, and you can `git reset --soft xyz` to make the branch label `dev` point back to commit `*`:

```
     tag:xyz
        |
        v
...--o--*   <-- HEAD -> dev
         \
          o--o--o   [only findable via reflogs]
```

Once you are done with this, simply delete the tag.

(Again, you can use a *branch or tag* name; use whichever you prefer; I illustrated this with a tag because a tag name is not *supposed* to move, while branch names *do* move.  They move *automatically*, in fact, whenever you `git checkout` the branch and then make commits or use `git reset`.  Tag names point to one particular commit and just stay there.)

---

Note, by the way, that you can use the search notation while creating a tag:

```
git tag xyz HEAD^{/publish/release:xyz}
```

That is, you identify *which commit to tag* when creating the tag name.  (The same is true for branch names, actually.)  You can then see this tag with `git log --decorate`, and graphical viewers like `gitk` generally show you which commits have which tags as well.

(Searching and tagging is a good way to transition to this better, at least in theory, habit.)

Comment: This is a little over my head - basically you are saying to use a tag instead of counting commit message logs?

Comment: You are right that not all development will happen on dev...in the future there will be feature branches that will get merged into dev, although right now i do all development directly on dev branch

Comment: @AlexanderMills: "basically you are saying to use a tag instead of counting commit message logs?" Yes, it's much simpler and and shows up nicely in `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` output (or other graph viewers).

Comment: ok I am going to do my best to give your methodology a shot. if you think it's a good question pls upvote, thx

Comment: BTW the one drawback to tags is that if you push them, everyone else tends to get them: they can be hard to stamp out at that point. But they don't get pushed by default; just remember not to use `git push --tags` (which pushes *all* your tags) if you have a bunch of these "temporary tags" around. (To push a single tag on purpose, you can just `git push v2.3` or whatever the tag's name is.)

Comment: ok, so let me get this straight, are these the steps wrt to the tagging approach? (1) on branch dev, checkout a temp branch (2) git reset --soft tagname (tagname is from the last time you tagged and should always be the same for ease of remembering?) (3) git tag xyz (does this do a commit, by default?) (4) git push origin master -f (5) git checkout dev (6) git merge temp....is that it?

Comment: if you could revise the steps I just mentioned and put them in your answer, I think your answer will help more people! thx

Comment: Well, steps 1-3 make sense. Step 4 pushes `master`—that is, it pushes *your* master to *their* master, but you haven't *changed* master, so I'm not sure what the intent is here. After that I'm confused what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: well dev is much different than master, I have been doing development for a week, and now that all tests pass etc etc, I want to publish private/dev to public/master. Am I missing a step in the above 6 steps? Perhaps I missing a new commit after reset --soft but before git tag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127580/discussion-between-torek-and-alexander-mills).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your `dev` branch tracks `master` before you start your work. If not, create a new branch before making any temporary commits.

To determine the point you branched off from `master` (and thus the point to reset back to), do:

```
git merge-base master HEAD
```

You can show all commits between that point and `HEAD` (this should include all your temporary commits, and only those commits) with:

```
git log --oneline $(git merge-base master HEAD)..HEAD
```

You can pipe the output of that command to `wc -l` and get the number of commits, which is the number you need for your `git reset` command.

Alternatively, you can get that number directly with:

```
git rev-list --count $(git merge-base master HEAD)..HEAD
```

Putting it all together:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~$(git log --oneline $(git merge-base master HEAD)..HEAD | wc -l)
```

Or:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~$(git rev-list --count $(git merge-base master HEAD)..HEAD)
```

After doing the reset, rather than merge `squash_branch` into `dev`, it might be better to do a hard reset instead (after you've verified that nothing is broken of course):

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard squash_branch
```

Also, merge conflicts tend to happen for a reason, so I'd be wary about blindly force-pushing to the remote. If you *must* force-push, then do this instead:

```
git push origin master --force-with-lease
```

The `--force-with-lease` flag will cause Git to overwrite any commits that you have already fetched, but the command will fail if the remote has new commits that you don't know about.

Comment: Thanks this looks good, so you are saying that i should merge the squash branch back into dev..also i added a comment to the original question to clarify and what do you think of toreks answer?

Comment: @AlexanderMills If you don't have any changes on `dev` (which you won't if you're doing this right away), it shouldn't be necessary to merge if you don't care about the history of "temp123" commits. If you have more questions about your workflow, feel free to [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about it. torek's answer looks good too (I've upvoted it); the tag suggestion was an idea I also had, so I'd go with that if your branching workflow prevents you from using my solution.

Comment: yeah I think in the long run, there will be branches off of dev, so yeah probably good to try the tag approach